# memory loss in the following C code

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am getting memory loss of 16 byte in the following code for queuing. Could you please let me know how can get rid of this problem? The code is:

```
      void enqueue( enqueuenode * queueNode1 ,bplus *bplusNew){
      [98] -> enqueue *queue=NULL;
              queue = malloc(sizeof(enqueue_node));
              queue->bplus = bplusNew;
              queue->next= NULL;
                if(queueNode1->headNode == NULL){
                   queueNode1->headNode=queueNode1->tailNode = queue ;
                   }
                 else{
                 queueNode1->tailNode->next = queue;
                 queueNode1->tailNode = queue;
                 }
            }
```

Following are two strucutres

```
         typedef struct enqueue_help{
           bplus bplusNode;
           struct enqueue_help * next;
         }*enqueue,enqueue_node;

        typedef struct enqueuenode_help{
          enqueue  headNode;
          enqueue  tailNode;
        }*enqueuenode,enqueuenode_node;
```

And for the above code following is the valgrind output:

```
             =23800== 272 (16 direct, 256 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 12
             ==23800==    at 0x4C2260E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
             ==23800==    by 0x4024BD:  enqueue(bplus.c:98)
             ==23800==    by 0x40260A:  PrintBplus (bplus.c:202)
             ==23800==    by 0x40286F: main (bplus.c:1251)
             ==23800==
```

Here `enqueuenode` is the pointer for the structure which holds two `enqueue` as a head node and tail node. This is for traversal of queue during dequeuing. Each `queue` is a pointer for the structure which holds some node address which needs to be queued.

Comment: Is that the whole function ? Are you sure you're subsequently freeing the node that you allocated here ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in that function. It has to be a place in your program where the deallocation takes place. There should be the problem. The memory loss is reported here because it is where it is reserved.

Comment: How are `enqueue`, `enqueuenode` and `ENQUEUE_NODE` related?

Comment: @Oli ENQUEUE_NODE is type.I edited the one.

Comment: Regarding typos and confusion, you're asking for trouble surely, by having enqueue_node and *enqueuenode.  I've seen this pattern before where a different name is defined for a pointer to a structure, but to me it seems like a bad idea every time I've seen it - you can already see when you are dealing with a pointer, without having a different name.  Can't you just name the structures enqueue and enqueue_node.  If you need pointers to either, just use enqueue* and enqueue_node*

Answer (score 5):

This is where you allocated the lost memory.

Valgrind cannot report where you lost it, it only can keep track of allocations and deallocations.

Maybe you lose some nodes in one of your algorithms, which should be easy to test since the number of nodes decreases, but it's also possible that there is a bug in the code that frees the data structure.

Comment: I have other losses like **indirectly loss, still reachable**. This is the only **definitely lost**,What do you think, is this **definite lost** is due to other losses? Should i go for resolving others first?

Comment: well fix all of them, probably this one first.. you know an enqueue* is lost, if you're lazy to re-read and verify all your code just trace(print) allocations and frees in run your code, it should be visible where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why a pointer to `enqueue` is assigned a memory block that's sized for an `enqueuenode`?

```
  [98] -> enqueue *queue=NULL;
          queue = malloc(sizeof(enqueuenode));
```

If, as you say, `enqueuenode` contains two `enqueue`'s, the second one could be the memory you're missing.

Comment: Sorry again typo mistake. I hadn't copy and pasted the code. So got some error. Enqueue is the pointer for the structure **enqueue_node** and **enqueuenode** is pointer for the structure **enqueuenode_node**.This **enqueuenode_node** contains two pointer for **enqueue_node**.

Comment: This is why I don't like `typedef`'s ;-)

Comment: I have added those structures. I hope that will make you more clear